# Ctrl+Shift+Space equivalent in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt-creator, hotkeys

In Visual Studio (with VAssistX at least), I can use Ctrl+Shift+Space to show this kind of tooltip for any function in which the cursor is currently in. In Qt Creator this tooltip is shown only when you first type the function call, so I have to go and delete the opening parenthesis, then type it again, which fools the editor that I just started typing function call and it shows the tooltip.

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you press **Ctrl+Space** when the cursor is on either side of the opening brace of the function then Qt Creator shows the tooltip.

You can also write a comma (and then delete it) to force the tooltip to appear - writing a comma anywhere between the braces will show the tooltip.

Comment: And it's called `Complete This` in `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard`, could change the shortcut there.

Comment: in Qt 6.0.2 it's `Ctrl+Shift+D`